# Unable to connect to VPS GUI

Tags: 18.04, gui

I set new VPS Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS 64bit
But i am unable to connect to gui.
First i tried

```
$ sudo tasksel install ubuntu-desktop
$ startx
$ sudo service gdm3 start
```

unable to connect via tightvncviewer error"tightvnc viewer no connection could be made because the target machine"

next tried

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
$ sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
$ sudo apt install tasksel -> select ubuntu dekstop and reboot
```

but there is no guy after connection.

I will be thankful for any advice still new in servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i just needed to add VNCserver.